# Constructing borders for rectangles in Game of life

Tags: python, graphics, conways-game-of-life

I just started my first programming course in Python and I'm having trouble understanding what's wrong with my code for Game of life. Our task is to create the grid that the game will play in but I can't understand what is wrong with my code (see below).

```
def paint(target_window, grid):

    height = len(grid)
    width = len(grid[0])

    target_window.setCoords(0,height,width,0)


    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            rect = Rectangle(Point(row,col),Point(row + 1, col + 1))
        rect.draw(target_window)
    target_window.update()
```

More specific the grid is supposed to be "infinite" so that the game isn't restricted. I think that my `.setCoords` may have something to do with what's wrong.

Comment: What do you expect to happen and what's happening instead?

Comment: The `rect.draw` line looks suspicious to me. Maybe it must be indented one level deeper so that it is part of the `for col` loop?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I agree, but we cannot be sure that this wasn't caused by transferring the code to SO.

Comment: What module is used for the graphics? This [Graphics](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html)? Is the `target_window.setCoords(0,height,width,0)` correct?

Comment: @mrkrieger1 The rect.draw was indented that way when i wrote the code. I will try to run the code again having it indented deeper!

Comment: @Wolf that's why I ask here.

Comment: @HampusEriksson but you still haven't told us what the actual problem is. Do you get an exception? Does the grid not look as you expect?

Comment: @mkrieger1 there was only a hint *`I think that my .setCoords may have something to do with what's wrong.`* and none about the expected results... Interesting, how clearly askers point out **that** *there must be something wrong* - if it wasn't, they wouldn't ask here ;-)

Comment: @mrkrieger1 The problem was that the whole grid was not showing up in my target window (I could see a glimpse of it in the bottom of the window). It was like the program would understand to draw a grid but it did not put it right. However your solutions have helped me and i can now see my grid clear as day! Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using [this Graphics library](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html), indeed your call of `setCoords` is wrong. Try to change it into this

```
target_window.setCoords(0,0,width,height)
```

The documentation says

> setCoords(xll, yll, xur, yur) Sets the coordinate system of the window. The lower-
>   left corner is (xll, yll) and the upper-right corner is (xur, yur). All subsequent drawing
>   will be done with respect to the altered coordinate system (except forplotPixel).

... and there is also issue with the indentation of `rect.draw(target_window)`, as [mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692169/constructing-borders-for-rectangles-in-game-of-life#comment53227844_32692169) pointed out.